# Why is grep -H returning bizarre output here?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I performed a grep -H command on a specified file, and the output is some weird mix of some strings of the file, instead of the usual filepath and matching string line I expected. The string I was searching for did not even appear in the output.

Why did this behavior occur? I first was doing a recursive grep and only a single file failed with this behavior. When I do a grep -l the filepath appears correctly.

Edit:
cat filename does not contain any output. cat -v shows the files output, and the file contains windows line endings (^M). Emacs lists the file as being a mac file, not a DOS file. After running mac2unix commands are working appropriately

Comment: Doesn't the file contain `$'\r'` that moves the cursor back to the beginning of the line, possibly overwriting what's been printed before?

Comment: the file does not contain the sequence`$'\r'`. I just tried to cat the file and nothing appeared in the output either. Emacs opens the file correctly.

Comment: `$'\r'` is a bash way of denoting the `x0d` character, also known as the Carriage Return.

Comment: I recognize the carriage return, but why the `$`?

Comment: Because `'\r'` is just two characters, ` \ ` and `r`, while `$'\r'` is the CR, as the dollared single quotes turn on ANSI C escaping rules.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you for the information! When I grep for the carriage return (`grep $'\r' filepath`), I still get the initial garbled result. Even with the file definitely containing carriage returns.

Comment: Any ideas what Linux, and `grep` version your working against? On Linux it really makes a difference. Thanks. :)

Comment: GREP -- 2.20, Linux -- CentOS release 6.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file lacks linefeeds (a.k.a. 0x0a, \n, LF, or ^J) between lines like a proper Unix/Linux text file, grep sees it as one very long line. Using 'cat' without '-v' results in the carriage returns (a.k.a. 0x0d, \r, CR, or ^M) returning the terminal cursor to the start of the line, and depending on your tty settings and whether the last line is empty (i.e. ^M^M) that may result in "nothing" visually because the last line of content has been cleared by the empty line. Using grep on the file only further confuses what is going on, since it may be playing games with the terminal as well (particularly if you use --color, as some Linux distros do by default.)

And FWIW: Emacs calling it a "mac" file and the "mac2unix" utility are both a bit anachronistic. The last Mac system to use CR-only line breaks was Mac OS 9, released almost 20 years ago.

Comment: Yes it is a bit anachronistic, but the code base is about that old.